# C++ "Dictionary as Hash Table with Linked List" problems

Tags: c++, linked-list, hashtable

I just started working with hash tables and linked lists and I was given this assignment involving them.

I am to Create a Dictionary using the text file "words.txt" as a Hash Table with Linked List to spell check a text file called "gettysburg_address.txt".

I am given the source code for the "HashTable class with linked list" as followed :

hashtable.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include "listtools.h"
#include "listtools.cpp"
#include "hashtable.h"

using LinkedListSavitch::Node;
using LinkedListSavitch::search;
using LinkedListSavitch::headInsert;
using namespace std;

#define HASH_WEIGHT 31

namespace HashTableSavitch
{
   HashTable::HashTable()
   {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
     hashArray[i] = NULL;
    }
   }

   HashTable::~HashTable()
   {
     for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
     {
       Node<string> *next = hashArray[i];
       while (next != NULL)
       {
         Node<string> *discard = next;
     next = next->getLink( );
     delete discard;
       }
     }
   }

   unsigned int HashTable::computeHash(string s) const
   {
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.length( ); i++)
    {
        hash = HASH_WEIGHT * hash + s[i];
    }
    return hash % SIZE;
   }

   bool HashTable::containsString(string target) const
   {
    int hash = this->computeHash(target);
    Node<string>* result = search(hashArray[hash], target);
    if (result == NULL)
       return false;
    else
       return true;
   }

   void HashTable::put(string s)
   {
    int hash = computeHash(s);
    if (search(hashArray[hash], s) == NULL)
    {
      // Only add the target if it's not in the list
      headInsert(hashArray[hash], s);
    }
   }
} // HashTableSavitch
```

I am suppose to do the following :

1.Display any misspelled word (A word is considered misspelled if its not in the dictionary)

2.Count the number of collisions for each cell of the Hash Table when loading the dictionary "words.txt",
and store/display the data 20 per line

3.Count the number of words that are misspelled and are correct 
- In each case, count the number of operations performed and store/display these numbers
- Also, store/display the average number of operations for a misspelled and correct word
- Note : "number of operations" refers to the number of nodes visited in the linked list for each word

This is what I have so far :

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include "hashtable.h"
using namespace std;
using HashTableSavitch::HashTable;

void upToLow(string & str);
void removePunct(string & str);

int main()
{
    HashTable h;
    string currWord;
    string word;
    int countMisspelled = 0;
    int countCorrect = 0;

    //Get input from words.rtf
    ifstream dictionary("words.txt");

    //File checking
    if (dictionary.fail())
    {
        cout << "File does not exist" << endl;
        cout << "Exit program" << endl;
    }

    //Create the dictionary as a hash table
    while(dictionary >> currWord)
    {
        h.put(currWord);
    }
    dictionary.close();

    //Get input from gettysburg_address.txt
    ifstream input("gettysburg_address.txt");

    //File checking
    if (input.fail())
    {
        cout << "File does not exist" << endl;
        cout << "Exit program" << endl;
    }

    //Spell check gettysburg_address.txt
    cout << "Misspelled words : " << endl;
    cout << endl;

    //If a word is not in the dictionary assume misspelled
    while(input >> word)
    {
        removePunct(word);
        upToLow(word);
        if(h.containsString(word) == false)
        {
            countMisspelled++; // Increment misspelled words count
            cout << word << " ";
            if(countMisspelled % 20 == 0) // Display misspelled words 20 per line
            {
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            countCorrect++; // Increment correct words count
        }
    }
    input.close();

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Number of misspelled words : " << countMisspelled << endl;
    cout << "Number of correct words : " << countCorrect << endl;

    return 0;
}


/*Function to convert uppercase letters to lowercase*/
void upToLow(string & str)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(str.c_str()); i++)
         if (str[i] >= 0x41 && str[i] <= 0x5A)
              str[i] = str[i] + 0x20;
}


/*Function to remove punctuation from string*/
void removePunct(string & str)
{
    str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(&ispunct)),str.end());
}
```

I've managed so far to spell check the text file given and display the words that are misspelled and the counts for "correct" and "misspelled". But I don't really know what I should do for counting the collisions and operations. My instructor very briefly went over hash tables and linked lists so I am quite a noob at this.

For counting the number of collisions, would I compare the hash value for each string in "words.txt" and if the hash value is the same, increment a counter for the number of collisions? Not quite sure how I would go about doing this.

I have no idea how I would go about counting the "number of operations performed". Any ideas for this?

Note again : "number of operations" refers to the number of nodes visited in the linked list for each word.

Any tips/help on how I should solve these problems is very much appreciated.

Comment: `#include`-ing implementation files is a bad idea, if you can avoid it

Comment: @TaylorFlores especially if you already included that same files `.h`

Comment: @Durk944 I think it would be easiest to count collisions when the table is being created, like in an `else` statement in your `put` function. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @TaylorFlores #include -ing those files is required unfortunately. And yes, counting the collisions when the table is being created is what I'm trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: @Durk944 by the looks of it, it's probably not required. The only reason I can think of for including an implementation file is if you're using templates (but in your case you would already have a header file to put them in). In my last comment, I was trying to imply the question: why can't you just implement a simple counter variable to count the collisions in your `put` statement? it's blatantly simple. Do you mean you need to count the collisions for each slot?

Comment: @TaylorFlores listtools uses templates which is why I have to include the implementation file. And my apologies I should of been a bit more clear in my question. Yes, I have to count the collisions for each slot which is making me very confused on how I would go about doing it.

Comment: Just verified with my instructor, I have to count each time I encounter a collision for each slot. I am still confused on how I would go about doing it.